# How to create two tables having same primary key but one is actually a foreign key also?

Tags: mysql

[image: Here is the table relationship]

I am trying to use java to create a database, but I am not sure how to make artist table's primary key refers back to artartist table, I set artistID in table artartist to auto_increment. would this code work?

CREATE TABLE artartist(
artistID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
artworkID MEDIUMINT,
PRIMARY KEY(artistID)
);

CREATE TABLE artist (
artistID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL (should I put auto_increment here too?)
Lname varchar(30),
Fname varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY (artistID),
FOREIGN KEY (artistID) REFERENCES artartist(artistID)
);

I am not sure what the best practice here is, I just want to link these two tables together without creating extra foreign keys that serves no other purposes.

thanks much for the help.

Comment: Why do you need the artartist table?  If each artwork only has one artist, you could just put the artistID column directly on the artwork table.  But if an artwork can have multiple artists, then the primary key on artartist would EITHER have to be artistID and artworkID taken together, OR a brand new id column.

Comment: ArtistID in ArtArtist must be the ArtistID from the Artist table - it cannot increment on its own. If the purpose of ArtArtist is to resolve a many to many relationship between the other two tables, its primary key is ArtistID, ArtworkID (composite primary key). Each of those on its own is also a foreign key.